# Dropdown missing some values

Tags: cakephp, select, concatenation, form-fields

I have a select-input-field which works well, but some Users are not in this list, allthough the database looks good and i have no conditions. I combine the option-texts with a $virtualFields which looks like `$virtualFields = array( 'full_name_withTitle' => 'CONCAT(lastname, " ", firstname, " (", title, ")")'`

allthough i have the title in brackets the empty line with no value should at least have " ( )" when there are no values.

the field looks like:

[image: select input field with missing lines]

any hints apreciated

```
endo
```

Comment: Can we see the code that generates the options? Also, if it's a `find('list')`, have you changed it to `find('all')` and debugged the output to see what records are returned?

Answer (score 1):

> allthough i have the title in brackets the empty line with no value should at least have " ( )" when there are no values

No. If one argument is null, CONCAT returns null.

[CONCAT doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

> CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following code while defining virtualFields:

```
$virtualFields = array( 'full_name_withTitle' => 'CONCAT(IF(lastname IS NULL '', lastname), " ", IF(firstname IS NULL, '', firstname), " (", IF(title IS NULL, '', title), ")")'
```

[This link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,94227,94227) would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you have character encoding problems, perhaps your database field has non-UTF8 encoded strings but PHP/CakePHP is expecting UTF8. Specifically `htmlspecialchars()` (or Cake's `h()`, which it wraps), [will silently output an empty string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) if it finds invalid characters.

Fixing this kind of problem can sometimes be tricky because there is no visibility for character encoding. If the whole database is small and non-UTF8 sometimes the easiest thing is to dump the database as SQL, convert using an editor or command line tool and re-import the database. Some quick searching found some [possibly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986510/converting-latin-mysql-data-to-utf8) [useful](http://nicj.net/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8/) posts on the topic.